# Soluble simple groups

Tags: group-theory

I am trying to prove the following:

$G$ is a finite group. Prove if there is no non-abelian simple group whose order divides $|G|$, then $G$ is soluble.

I think it would be easier to prove
$G$ insoluble implies there is a non abelian simple group with order dividing $|G|$ but I'm not sure how to approach.

This is homework

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course we can assume that $G$ is non-abelian, since we have nothing to show otherwise. The assumption then in particular implies that $G$ itself is not simple, hence there is a proper non-trivial normal subgroup. Note that the assumptions are trivially also satisfied for $N$ and $G/N$, hence $G/N$ and $N$ are soluble by induction. This shows that $G$ is soluble.